# Netty Simple channel handler disconnection is get blocked

Tags: java, netty

My Netty channel handler `channelClosed ()` is get blocked while another message being received at `messageReceived()`. 
I used `OrderedMemoryAwareThreadPoolExecutor` for synchronising messages.
Is `channelClosed()` processed by low priority thread.?

Could you please tell about thread priority in netty. 
Thank you

```
    objChannelPipeline.addLast("ipFilter", objCustomIPFilterHandler);
    objChannelPipeline.addLast("idleHandler", new IdleStateHandler(timer,5,5, 0));
    objChannelPipeline.addLast("loggingHandler", objLoggingHandler);        
    objChannelPipeline.addLast("frameDecoder",
            new DelimiterBasedFrameDecoder(Integer.MAX_VALUE, false, ChannelBuffers.copiedBuffer("\n\n".getBytes(CharsetUtil.UTF_8))));
    objChannelPipeline.addLast("messageDecoder", new CustomMessageDecoder());
    objChannelPipeline.addLast("groupOrder", executionHandler);
    objChannelPipeline.addLast("ProtocolMultiplexer", CustomHandler);
```

Answer (score 2):

I guess this is because you are using `OrderedMemoryAwareThreadPoolExecutor`, in this case events will be executed in the order in which they happen. Hence `messageReceived()` will always execute before `channelClose()`.

So if you have received 3 message received and after that the channel is closed, then first three times `messageReceived` will be executed and after that only `channelClose()` will be executed.

If you use `MemoryAwareThreadPoolExecutor` than in this case `channelClose` can get invoked before `messageReceived()` as here the execution of events are not ordered.

Hope this helps !!

Comment: The scenario is one channel is closed, at the same time another channel is connected and a message is received through that channel.

Comment: @user2067201. In that case also `messageReceived` can be invoked before `channelClose()` event as they are happening on different channel. But there is no thread priority associated with the events so they can happen in any order.

Comment: Thank You for your reply.I got channel closed event first, but when messageReceived()m

Comment: Thank You for your reply. I got channel closed event first, but when `messageReceived ()` event occurs the code written in `channelClose ()` gets blocked and executing the code written in the `messageReceived ()`. The blocked code executes only after completing the code written on `messageReceived()`.

Comment: @user2067201. Now I need to see the code, without that I'll be just be able to do guess work only. One question I have is how you are identifying that `channelClosed` is blocked till `messageReceived` is executed and this `messageReceived` is on second channel, not on the one which is closed.

Comment: I logged the entry and exit for methods `channelClosed` and `messageReceived`.This case occurs when `channelClosed` and `channelConnected` occurs simultaneously.

Comment: @user2067201. Sorry Man!! I am out of guesses now :-). May be you could try increasing the size of your pool, as you threads may all be occupied and hence blocking.